# How can grouping `block` element inside in '<p class="p">' element?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to grouping `<block>` element in inside the `<p class="p">` element. If `<p class="p">` following-sibling[1] is `<block>` element and `<p class="p1">` value inside in `<p class="p">` element.
**Input XML File-:**

```
<root>
    <p class="p">aaaaaa</p>
    <block>
        <p>block</p>
    </block>
    <p class="p1"> bbb </p>
    <block>
        <p>block</p>
    </block>
    <p class="p1">bbb.</p>
    <p class="p">cccc</p>
</root>
```

I want to expected output below.
**Output XML file:**

```
<root>
    <p class="p">aaaaaa<block><p>block</p></block> bbb <block><p>block</p></block>bbb.</p>
    <p class="p">cccc</p>
</root>
```

Can we right the logic another way to above the output, I am using XSLT below above the output:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="p[@class='p']">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][self::block]">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;p&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <p><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></p>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="p[@class='p1']">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][self::p[@class='p']]">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/p&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am not able to understand what needs to be done here, not from your example nor from your explanation. In general, you should never have to use `disable-output-escaping` to generate markup.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I want to insert `block` elements in inside the `p` element. Could you please see my expected output?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I edited more clarifications, could you please look into this? I will appreciated to you.

Comment: I am afraid it's not any clearer. If you want to start a new group at every `<p class="p">`, that's relatively simple. I don't understand the condition of "if ...". You need to describe 2 situations, one where the condition is true and one where it is false, and explain what should happen in either case.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, if you don't understand my `if` condition then yo can ignore `ìf` condition. you can wright the code or share your input according to my expected output.

Comment: No I can't, because I don't understand the logic of your output. If you can use XSLT 2.0, look into `xsl:for-each-group` with `group-starting-with`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to wrap/group the right nodes for the input sample but I am not sure it implements your requirements, I haven't quite understood them.

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p[@class = 'p']">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), current-group() except ."/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion the output is good see the following link [http://xsltransform.net/93FbNXL] but I have one question, can we `p[@class = 'p']` match the rule in template example(`<xsl:template match="p[@class = 'p']">`) instead of match the `root` in template? because I have also used `identity template` in xsl file copy for the other elements.

Comment: @Yug, the posted code assumes you have the identity template set up as well, as otherwise the `apply-templates` wouldn't output the nodes in a group. But `for-each-group` is usually done in a template matching a parent or ancestor, I don't see how you would want to use it if you match on a sibling.

Comment: Martin Honnen, Thanks for the reply.